# webpack --watch && http-server ./dist -p 8080 --cors -o not working

Tags: node.js, npm

```
 "server:dev": "webpack --watch && http-server ./dist -p 8080 --cors -o -d false"
```

When I run `npm run server:dev`, the script starts --watch but http-server is not running. If I shuffle the statements then http-server is running and webpack is not watching. I know webpack-dev-server solves the problem but I want to have one simple command that watches changes and starts server in browser when I build it.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @nemesv windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a cross-platform solution, take a look at the package [`npm-run-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "server:webpack": "webpack --watch",
    "server:start": "http-server ./dist -p 8080 --cors -o -d false",
    "serve": "npm-run-all --parallel server:*"
  }
}
```